# Possible number of groups of order N

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, groups-enumeration

When is the number of groups of some order $n$ greater than $n$? For example, lets say this happens at $n=3$, then that would mean that there are more groups of order 3 than 3.

Comment: http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_2%5En

Comment: $n=32$ is the smallest such $n$. There are $51$ isomorphism types of groups of order $32$.

Comment: I don't think there is any known $n>1$ for which there are exactly $n$ groups of order $n$.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by Derek Holt in the comment, $n=32$ is the smallest $n$ such that there are more than $n$ groups of order $n$. This can be easily checked using the [Small Groups Library](http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/sgl.html) which is contained in the computational algebra system [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org):

```
gap> First([1..100],n -> NrSmallGroups(n)>n);
32
gap> NrSmallGroups(32);
51
gap> List([1..32],NrSmallGroups);
[ 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 5, 2, 2, 1, 5, 1, 2, 1, 14, 
1, 5, 1, 5, 2, 2, 1, 15, 2, 2, 5, 4, 1, 4, 1, 51 ]
```

Regarding $n>1$ such that there are exactly $n$ groups of order $n$, this has been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1547948/) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/224636/), and no such $n$ is currently known.